# Wordpress rewrite rules on every post

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have a site about downloading Apps, when the visitors click on the download buttons

Example: https://deskrush.com/camp-pinewood-2-apk/

The visitors will go to
https://deskrush.com/camp-pinewood-2-apk/?target=download&index=0

I want the link to be
https://deskrush.com/camp-pinewood-2-apk/download/0

But I want to do that for all APK posts template

I tried this code it works perfectly but The issue is that I need to flush rewrite rules every time I publish a new post, any fix for this?

```
 function simple_blog_add_rewrite_rule()
{
    $args = [
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'single-apk.php'
    ];
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if ($posts) {

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            add_rewrite_rule(
                $post->post_name . '/([^/]+)/?$',
                'index.php?name=' . $post->post_name . '&target=$matches[1]',
                'top'
            );
            add_rewrite_rule(
                $post->post_name . '/download/([^/]+)/?$',
                'index.php?name=' . $post->post_name . '&target=download&index=$matches[1]',
                'top'
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'simple_blog_add_rewrite_rule');

function simple_blog_add_query_vars_filter($vars)
{
    $vars[] = "target";
    $vars[] = "index";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'simple_blog_add_query_vars_filter');
```

Comment: Please add some code. What have you tried so far? Where did you define the redirects? Please include your `.htaccess` or `nginx.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

in your functions.php

This handles the redirect.

```
function custom_add_rewrite_rule(){
    
   
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post') );
  
    if( $posts ){
        
        foreach($posts as $post ){
            
            add_rewrite_rule( 
                $post->post_name . '/download/([^/]+)/?$', 
                'index.php?name=' . $post->post_name . '&target=download&index=$matches[1]', 
                'top' 
            );   
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_add_rewrite_rule');
```

Then add the custom [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/)

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "target";
    $vars[] = "index";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

now in your template you can call it back by accessing the query:

```
get_query_var('target');
get_query_var('index');
```

Comment: the code is working perfectly but needs to flush rewrite rules when I publish a new post, any fix for this?

Comment: see this answer [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334880/how-do-i-flush-rewrite-rules](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334880/how-do-i-flush-rewrite-rules)